# How does the InsertionMode.Replace works on the Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, ajax.beginform

i have the following `Ajax.beginform` inside my asp.net mvc view, where the result of the ajax call will replace the  `<div id= "searcharea">`, as follow:-

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Patient",
    new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "searcharea",
    LoadingElementId = "progress2"
}))
{
   <table >

 <tr>

        <th>
         Searching By First Name (English) :-
        </th>
        <th>
          <input type="text" name="firstname"  />
        </th></tr>
      <tr>

        <th>
         Searching By Family Name (English) :-
        </th>
        <th>
          <input type="text" name="familyname"  />
        </th></tr>

      <input type="submit" value="Search      " /></th><th></th></tr>
  </table>

}

<div id = "progress2">
<img src= "@Url.Content("~/Content/images/Ajax-loader-bar.gif") ">
</div>
<p>
<div id= "searcharea">
</div>
```

So at the begining i though that i will only be able to perform one search since the `<div id= "searcharea">` will be replaced with the result of the ajax call and it will not be avilalbe after that, and if i try to do anther ajax call there will be no more `<div id= "searcharea">` to replace the result with.

But what actually happened is that I was able to do multiple searches without any problem ,, so does this means that the `InsertionMode.Replace` will not replace the DOM element and that it will only insert the result of the ajax call within this DOM,, **because i can not understand how i can reference a DOM element multiple times even if it has been replaced by my first ajax call** ???!! can anyone explain how this happen ?
BR

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're misunderstanding `InsertionMode.Replace`. It will replace everything **inside** the HTML element you specify with `UpdateTargetId`, not the element itself.

It's the same as

```
$("#searcharea").html(newHTMLcontent);
```

An insertion mode that destroyed the element it worked with wouldn't be very useful for the reason you mentioned: you'd only be able to use it once.

Comment: Yes i know that insertionmode.replace should replace the UpdateTargetid with the result of the method call ,, but what happened is that i can reference the UpdateTargetid more than one time, which means that the UpdateTargetid was not replaced actually ,, so i was trying to understand what is happening...

Comment: Reread my answer. Insertion mode replace does NOT replace the UpdateTargetId. It replaces everything inside the UpdateTargetId.

Comment: >An insertion mode that destroyed the element it worked with wouldn't be very useful
Why? I'm really missing this mode to replace the partial view with its updated version: I could simply wrap the partial with some div. Now I have to find all the places with this partial and wrap the RenderPartial call :\

Comment: Yea, I agree with Alleo. Been using MVC a while but only realised now that Replace does INSIDE and not the entire thing. Hmmm. Very strange. You can easily bind to dynamic object iwth jQuery

Comment: Hey guys. I know I'm pretty late to the party. I'm rolling MVC 5.2.3 which was was released Feb 2015, and in that you can specify the InsertionMode as "ReplaceWith", which does what you're describing (replaces the DOM node itself, not just the inner html). It may have been included in earlier releases, but I know that it's at least in 5.2.3.